# Tomcat server error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

When i start the Tomcat server 9.x using Community Server Connector on VS code, i get an error:

> WARNING: java.io.tmpdir directory does not exist
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

[tomcat server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBpQQ.png)

How can i fix it?